# flutter build could not find core_ktx

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, android-ktx

I'm trying to build an android app from a flutter project that is previously working without problems
the error I got is

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeKoutDebugAssets'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:koutDebugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find core-ktx-1.8.0-alpha01.aar (androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0-alpha01).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/core/core-ktx/1.8.0-alpha01/core-ktx-1.8.0-alpha01.aar
   > Could not find core-1.8.0-alpha01.aar (androidx.core:core:1.8.0-alpha01).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/core/core/1.8.0-alpha01/core-1.8.0-alpha01.aar
   > Could not find core-1.8.0-alpha01.aar (androidx.core:core:1.8.0-alpha01).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/core/core/1.8.0-alpha01/core-1.8.0-alpha01.aar
   > Could not find core-1.8.0-alpha01.aar (androidx.core:core:1.8.0-alpha01).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/core/core/1.8.0-alpha01/core-1.8.0-alpha01.aar
   > Could not find core-1.8.0-alpha01.aar (androidx.core:core:1.8.0-alpha01).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/core/core/1.8.0-alpha01/core-1.8.0-alpha01.aar
   > Could not find core-1.8.0-alpha01.aar (androidx.core:core:1.8.0-alpha01).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/core/core/1.8.0-alpha01/core-1.8.0-alpha01.aar
   > Could not find core-1.8.0-alpha01.aar (androidx.core:core:1.8.0-alpha01).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/core/core/1.8.0-alpha01/core-1.8.0-alpha01.aar
   > Could not find core-1.8.0-alpha01.aar (androidx.core:core:1.8.0-alpha01).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/core/core/1.8.0-alpha01/core-1.8.0-alpha01.aar
```

I'm sure that I have an internet connection, and I also tried to copy and paste the URL mentioned in the error into the browser, the file has downloaded successfully

Comment: maybe this could resolve your issue ==> https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27254

Comment: Thanks it works

Comment: If its works then support back :-) THANKS Bro